# Locking certain tokens

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, bsc

I have a smart contract, and I would like to send tokens to my holders, however I would like to put a time lock on these tokens, as the holder to keep them for 2 months in their wallet, before they will be able to swap, send or even sell them.

Is there any function to do this ?

1. Any tokens coming from this wallet address, 2)To be locked for this time, 3)before they are unlocked)

Any one can advise me please?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a vested dapp website,  add modifier, or write a function. uint256 numbers are initialized to zero so the following code should work:

```
mapping(address => uint256) lockedAddress;
uint256 launch = block.timestamp;

modifier isLocked() {
     require(lockedAddress[msg.sender] < block.timestamp + 5184000);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks, Btw, do you have the time to look into my contract and make the changes for a fee (if this site allows paid services) please.

https://bscscan.com/address/0x4609467334e7c3a188f619141520ceecb070c2a4#code

Comment: I'll look it over and create a new one, please message me on telegram to discuss further, @Anon_Grunt

Comment: okay, I sent it you a DM on telegram